Is there an error in Russell & Norvig (4th edition)'s claim about A* with a consistent heuristic?
In "AI: A Modern Approach" (Russell & Norvig, 4th edition), section 3.5.2 "A* search" includes this sentence on page 88:

In addition, with a consistent heuristic, the first time we reach a state it will be on an optimal path, so we never have to re-add a state to the frontier, and never have to change an entry in reached.

There are three claims here:

The first time we reach a state it will be on an optimal path.
We never have to re-add a state to the frontier.
We never have to change an entry in reached.

I believe that claims (1) and (3) are false.  To see this easily, consider the heuristic $h(n) = 0$ for all $n$.  Clearly it is consistent.  With this heuristic, A* is just Dijkstra's algorithm.  But in Dijkstra's algorithm, the first time we reach a state (i.e. add it to the frontier, as defined on p. 72) it certainly might not be on an optimal path, and we may have to update its entry in reached (i.e. the parent pointer, as seen in the pseudocode in Figure 3.7 on p. 73) as soon as we discover a shorter path to it.
So is this simply an error in the book, or am I missing something here?


But in Dijkstra's algorithm, the first time we reach a state (i.e. add it to the frontier [..])

When they say "reach the state", they mean when the node is dequeued from the frontier, not when it is added to the frontier.
In Dijkstra's, when you dequeue a node, you know for certain you've reached the optimal path to that node.  The same is true of A* with a consistent heuristic.  However, it's not true when the heuristic is admissible-but-not-consistent.  In that case, it's possible that dequeuing the same node multiple times will be necessary.

Page 72 of the text says "We say that any state that has had a node generated for it has been reached (whether or not that node has been expanded)".  In other words, they consider a node to be reached when it is added to the frontier, not when it is dequeued.
I agree with everything you wrote in your second paragraph, but I don't think this proves their claim (1) to be true given their definition of "reached".

@AdamDingle Using that definition of "reached", then yes their claim is incorrect.
